# Concat objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two objects with the same structure and I want to concat them together using Javascript. Is there an easy way to do this?

```
var num = { '0': 0, '1': 0, '2': 0, '3': 0 };
var let = { 'A':'1', 'B':'2', 'C':'3' }
```

Comment: Those are JavaScript objects. There is nothing JSON related there.

Answer (score 3):

You can just use jQuery's [`.extend()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/):

```
$.extend(num,let); // num will now be the merged object.
```

Note: every duplicate index will have the value it had in `let`